# makedepend cannot rename makefile

Tags: c, makefile

after installing xutils-dev to get makedepend onto my Linux Mint 12 install, I have tried to compile a c program and produce exectuables by going the "make" command on the Makefile (directory architecture found here http://svn.clinrisk.co.uk/opensource/qrisk2/). However I get the following message:

```
makedepend: error: cannot rename Makefile to Makefile.bak
```

I have only seen issues such as this related to cygwin which I am not using. Is this an issue with the makedepend I have installed? Or is renaming something I can override?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a file permissions issue on the directory.
Make sure you have write permission on the directory.

As a general rule, run `make` as the same user that owns the files in the source code tree.
The owner will usually have write permissions on all the files and directories.
Other users usually don't, and that is as it should be.

I checked out QRISK2 and it follows this pattern.

Comment: hi and thanks for you're reply. I have run "sudo make" with no difference and "chmod -R 777" to give full permissions but still not difference.

Comment: I told you not to do that!  The `make` commands works fine for me. Are you running it as the user who also owns the directory?  (Do `ls -ld .` and `whoami` return the same username?)  Are the files on a network share or an NTFS partition?

Comment: ls -ld returns "drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 2014-02-12 12.52" and whoami returns "arron"

Comment: `root` shouldn't own these files!! Try this (as `arron`): `cp -pr . /tmp/qrisk2; cd /tmp/qrisk2; make`.

Comment: This works! I think using a shared folder from a mapped network was confusing permissions. thanks reinier.

Comment: Aaaah ... I bet it's NFS!

Answer (score 0):

Since you get an error message from `makedepend`, it seems it is installed. It's hard to tell from the error message what prevented it from renaming the file. It could be that it refuses to do so if there's `Makefile.bak` there already, or it could be due to permissions problems, or a host of other issues.

One way to find out what `makedepend` tried to do and why that failed is to run it under `strace`. See http://chadfowler.com/blog/2014/01/26/the-magic-of-strace/ for an introduction to `strace`.

Comment: thanks for you're reply. running as su doesn't help, and there isn't an existing Makefile.bak in the directory. I'll have a go with strace.